# Auto-Coloring Text | JS CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I would like to know if it is possible to auto color text, of any length using JavaScript and CSS. For example, if I use `contentEditable` on a h1 tag and a user edits it through their browser, it will return multicolored text in the same area. The first letter one color, the second another and so on. Not just 1 color, many colors.

Would it be possible to continue it with a 7 color pattern, or not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a little [proof of concept (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/68gyh4sc/1/). It basically gets the text of a div that is `contentEditable = true`, wraps each letter in a span and puts that into a div that is behind the input div. The coloring is then done with some CSS magic.

```
#input {position: absolute; opacity: 0.0;}
#rainbow {position: absolute; background: #cccccc;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+1) {color: blue;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+2) {color: green;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+3) {color: violet;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+4) {color: yellow;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+5) {color: cyan;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+6) {color: orange;}
#rainbow span:nth-child(7n+7) {color: red;}
```

Here's the JS:

```
function wrapInSpans(str) {
    wrappedStr = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        wrappedStr += "<span>" + str[i] + "</span>";
    }
    return wrappedStr;
}
function rewrapContent(objSrc, objTarget) {
    objTarget.innerHTML = wrapInSpans(objSrc.innerText);
}
input = document.getElementById("input");
input.contentEditable = true;
rainbow = document.getElementById("rainbow");
rainbow.contentEditable = true;
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
    rewrapContent(input, rainbow);
}, false);
rewrapContent(input, rainbow);
```

And the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="rainbow"></div>
    <div id="input">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Only issue currently is that the text cursor of the hidden input-div is also invisible. I'm not sure how to fix that, sorry.

Comment: Backspace does not work... I'm not sure I want to use it anymore.

Comment: backspace works for me

Comment: Does not work on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Works for me on Edge. Didn't work on Firefox, but I replaced `innerText` with `textContent` (fixed the jsfiddle link) and now it works on firefox, chrome and edge for me.

Comment: Yay I'll try it. Should work for me.